# Is it possible to use a javascript variable as a PHP array key?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to utilize a javascript variable as the key of a PHP array to `echo` out. Notice the javascript variable `id` is want I want to use as the key of the PHP array `$allNames[]`.

Is this possible? Without JSON/AJAX? If so please help.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    $('*[class^="spec"]').mouseover(function(){
        var the_class = $(this).attr("class");
        var id = the_class.replace("spec", "");
        $('#here').html('<?php echo $allNames[id]; ?>'); // here
    });
</script>
```

Many thanks.

Comment: PHP finishes execution on the server before javascript starts execution on the client. I don't see how it could be possible without something clever.

Comment: -1? Really? I can and have done PHP `echo` commands within javascript. It is entirely possible to inject PHP code in javascript.

Comment: That is not running PHP from javascript. The PHP echoes run first, then when the page reaches the client they execute whatever javascript is on the page - with the contents of the PHP echoes added into it. While the result of PHP code affects the javascript, the javascript is not RUNNING php code, only the result of it.

Comment: "It is entirely possible to inject PHP code in javascript" Yes it is. The other way around which you're trying is not.

Comment: granted. But at least only a simple `json_encode()` is needed.

Comment: Yes, `var jsVar = <?php echo json_encode($arrayOfStuff); ?>;` should make it a valid Object (from associate array) or JS array.

Comment: This is totally not worthy of -4 votes. A simple "No, that's not possible, but you can do this" was all that was necessary, and was given below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use AJAX, but it may be wasteful to do so in this case. Try this:

```
var allNames = <?php echo json_encode($allNames); ?>;
$('[class^="spec"]').mouseover(function() {
    var id = this.className.substr(4); // more efficient than previous code
    document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = allNames[id];
});
```

---

Alternatively, try refactoring your approach. Instead of having this (example)

```
<div class="spec1">Hover here</div>
```

Try this:

```
<div class="spec" data-hover="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($allNames[1]); ?>">Hover here</div>
```

Then your script could be as simple as:

```
$(".spec").mouseover(function() {
    document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = this.getAttribute("data-hover");
});
```

Comment: completely excellent. The first snippet here does the job exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. in client-side javascript the php has to already contain all of the variables already.

PHP is rendered before the javascript so you cannot create echo statements by javascript

If you want to dynamically generate HTML from the ajax, this can still be possible as the whole point of many javascript libraries such as jQuery is to dynamically modify elements in the Document Object by using selectors.

Comment: I can and have run PHP echo statements through JavaScript.

Comment: @Kolink it does: it tells him why he can't, and it then gives a suggestion based on an assumption about what he is ACTUALLY trying to do, which nobody really knows. I'm glad that you were able to help him though, it seemed like he was trying to do everything backwards

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it with JSON. Just call the PHP file like this

```
file.php?id=JAVASCRIPT_ID_HERE
```

Then in that PHP file, just use `$_GET['id']` to grab the ID

Comment: Granted this would work, but Kolink totally hit the nail on the head.

Comment: Glad to see you got your answer :)